# How to reach fragment from dialog that is launched from recyclerView

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, android-dialogfragment

So basically, I have a dialog where the user inputs data. This dialog is launched from a recyclerView with a custom adapter. I need to call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the fragment from the dialog after the user clicks "finish".

How do I do this?

Code:

```
public class FoodListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<FoodListAdapter.ViewHolder>
    implements View.OnClickListener {
    //blabla

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        int position = (int) v.getTag();
        String foodItemTitle = mFoodItemList.get(position).getTitle();

        FoodEditDietDialog dialog = new FoodEditDietDialog();
        dialog.show(fm, mFoodItemList.get(position).getTimeStamp());
    }


public class Fragment extends Fragment {
    //blabla

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

    foodList = databaseHelper.getList("somethingsomething");
    recyclerView = Fragment.findViewById(R.id.list);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(false);
    layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this.getContext());
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    adapter = new FoodListAdapter(fm, foodList);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
}

public class FoodEditDietDialog extends DialogFragment {
    //blabla

    button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            databaseHelper.doSomething();
            dismissDialog();
            //TODO: call method in dietFragment to notify adapters
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: are you opening Dialog inside adapter class or from fragment?

Comment: @RumitPatel from inside the custom adapter, through an onClick function.

Comment: you can simply call dialog.cancel(); and then notifyDataSetChanged(); it seems not be an issue.

Comment: @RumitPatel this is not possibly, as the dialog is dismissed from dialog window itself and the adapters are located at the fragment.

Comment: post your code. of adapter and dialog also.

Comment: @RumitPatel I added the code.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do this through your hosting `Activity`.

```
public interface DataChangeListener {
    void onDataChange();
}

public class YourActivity extends Activity implements DataChangeListener {

    private List<DataChangeListener> dataChangeListeners = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    public void onDataChange() {
        for(DataChangeListener listener in dataChangeListeners) {
            listener.onDataChange();
        }
    }

    public void addDataChangeListener(DataChangeListener listener) {
        dataChangeListeners.add(listener);
    }

    public void removeDataChangeListener(DataChangeListener listener) {
        dataChangeListeners.remove(listener);
    }
}

public class Fragment extends Fragment implements DataChangeListener {

    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        if (activity instanceOf YourActivity) {
            activity.addDataChangeListener(this)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        Activity activity = getActivity();
        if (activity instanceOf YourActivity) {
            activity.removeDataChangeListener(this)
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDataChange() {
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

public class FoodEditDietDialog extends DialogFragment {
    //blabla

    button = dialog.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            databaseHelper.doSomething();
            dismissDialog();

            //TODO: call method in dietFragment to notify adapters
            Activity activity = getActivity();
            if (activity instanceOf DataChangeListener) {
                activity.onDataChange();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

So basically, dialog will call activity, activity will notify fragment, fragment will notify adapters. Alternatively, you can pass your fragment (as DataChangeListener) to your adapter, and to your dialog. And call it from there.

Comment: At the Activity page, when overriding onDataChange, it doesn't seem to recognize the "in" part. It says "Cannot resolve symbol 'in' "

Comment: I replaced the 'in' with ':'. However, addDataChangeListener on the activity is not being called?

Comment: `addDataChangeListener` is not being called? Have added the `onAttach` method from the answer? Alternatively you can use `onAttach(Context context)` instead of `onAttach(Activity activity)`. One of them is not called based on the Android Version (however `onAttach(Activity activity)` should work)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The android said that the function was deprecated. Anyway, I changed the code like you said, however, nothing happens though. Maybe a broadcast would be another option for this problem?